# unset error puma-rails 5 on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3, puma

I am deploying my app using puma+nginx+capistrano on rails 5 and using this tutorial http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/. I performed all the steps. But when I do:

```
start puma-manager
```

I get following error:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", 
sender=":1.1" (uid=500 pid=2737 comm="start puma-manager ") 
interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)"
requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I am not able to start my app and what is the error here, I am not able to understand. How can I correct this?

Comment: did you check simply it with Capistrano not with puma manager ???

Comment: I ran 'cap production deploy'. Its all success and it is showing 
     ' Command restart sent success' under 'puma:restart'